# Supporting operations at multiple aggregation levels

Tags: c++, data-structures

Suppose I have struct or class that looks something like this:

`struct foo{
   string attribute_1;
   int    attribute_2;
   string attribute_3;`

int value_1;
   int value_2;
   double value_3;
};

What are some good ways of supporting aggregate operations on collections of foo across the different attributes? E.g. I might want to sum value_1 where attribute_1 is something, or where attribute 2 is something and attribute 3 is something.

I have been using boost::multi_index to do this but I'd like to hear how other people do this. Perhaps when you need this kind of ability, it's better to use to embed an in-memory database.  What have other people done for this?

Answer (score 0):

STL algorithms and functors will allow you to do this sort of thing in many ways.  For instance, to sum value_1 where attribute_1 is something, you could do something like (**DISCLAIMER: This hasn't been near a compiler**)

```
class MyFunctor
{
public:
    explicit MyFunctor(const string &str) : str_(str), sum_(0) {}
    bool operator() (const foo &f) const
    {
        if (f.attribute_1 == str_)
        {
            sum_ += f.value_1;
        }
    }
    int sum() const { return sum_; }

private:
    string str_;
    int    sum_;
};

...


std::cout << stl::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), MyFunctor("blah")).count() << std::endl;
```

where `v` is e.g. a `std::vector<foo>`.